# Cannot bundle for react-server-dom-webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-server-components

Webpack bundling is taken long time and finally failed when I add `createFromFetch` of `react-server-dom-webpack/client`.
If I remove `createFromFetch` from the code, bundling is finished soon.
After failed, `dist` dir has many bundler files.

[image]

This is the repo that I'm trying.

https://github.com/dhythm/ts-rsc-prisma/blob/c3bbe0d62335f9465bdaab0a40e24c7a99f0e53c/src/Root.client.tsx#L4

What I did

- compared the behavior of removing/adding `createFromFetch`.
- tried running webpack both npm-script style and node style that was referred for [server components demo](https://github.com/reactjs/server-components-demo/blob/main/scripts/build.js)
- run [server components demo](https://github.com/reactjs/server-components-demo/blob/main/scripts/build.js) and it worked well

What I'm expecting

- webpack runs successfully
- the client-side code can get chunk data from the server-side react.